# How do I create a barplot for a specific factor in a data frame?

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart, levels

Let's say I have a data frame as follows

```
Gender    Score  
Male      1  
Female    2  
Male      4  
Male      3  
Female    5
```

How would I create a barplot that only plotted the scores for males?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create a barplot that plots bars only for Male - Scores

```
 barplot(df[df$Gender == "Male","Score"],xlab="Scores of Males")
```